# Difference Between id-aes128-wrap vs aes128-wrap?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

In Node.js, `console.dir(getCiphers(), {'maxArrayLength': null})` outputs both `id-aes128-wrap` and `aes128-wrap`.  What's the difference between them?

Running `getCipherInfo` seems to indicate that the latter is just an alias for the former?

```
console.log(getCipherInfo('id-aes128-wrap'))
console.log(getCipherInfo('aes128-wrap'))
```

Returns:

```
{
  mode: 'wrap',
  name: 'id-aes128-wrap',
  nid: 788,
  blockSize: 8,
  ivLength: 8,
  keyLength: 16
}
{
  mode: 'wrap',
  name: 'id-aes128-wrap',
  nid: 788,
  blockSize: 8,
  ivLength: 8,
  keyLength: 16
}
```

Comment: Seem to be aliases, see [id-aes128-wrap](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d396a041f71cc055ad60b0abc63ad81c0ee6a574/deps/openssl/openssl/include/openssl/obj_mac.h#L2859) and [aes128-wrap](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/d396a041f71cc055ad60b0abc63ad81c0ee6a574/deps/openssl/openssl/crypto/evp/c_allc.c#L150).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the same thing; it's an alias.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34780776)

Comment: @swiss In what way is this *not* an answer?

Comment: Maybe not just written *"It’s an alias"*, but also provide facts about it. Or prove it's the same. Unfortunately this is already done a little bit in the question…